# Within Chrome browser with no libraries, how do I encode html5 audio as base64 data?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to record a 30 second sound clip in a Chrome browser and post the audio to a server as base64 encoded FLAC audio, and I feel like I'm 80% of the way there.

1. I can capture the audio into audioChunks when served off a HTTPS url - I think.
2. do I need to worry about the mediaRecorder.start parameter?  Why not use defaults?
3. Is there a better way to do the base64 conversion than a Blob to FileReader?  When I try to convert the base64 data back to the FLAC file on my desktop, it says bad characters, which I think means I did the first direction wrong.

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;

const DURATION_MS = 10 * 1000;

function getUserMediaPromise(constraints) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.info('Getting user media.');
    navigator.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: false
    }, function(stream) {
      console.info('Got stream!');
      resolve(stream);
    }, function(error) {
      console.error('Error getting stream!');
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}


function recordAudioPromise(stream) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var audioChunks = [],
      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        audioBitsPerSecond: 16000
      });
    mediaRecorder.start(5 * 1000); // One chunk of data per X seconds. Why do we care?

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.info('Stopping audio after ' + DURATION_MS + 'ms');
      mediaRecorder.stop();
    }, DURATION_MS);

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      console.info('data available', e.data.size);
      audioChunks.push(e.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onerror = reject;
    mediaRecorder.onwarning = reject;

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
      console.info('Stopped and converting to base64, state:', mediaRecorder.state);
      var blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
        type: 'audio/flac'
      });
      console.info('Created blob', blob.type, blob.size);
      audioChunks = [];
      var fileReader = new window.FileReader();
      fileReader.onloadend = function() {
        var base64data = fileReader.result;
        resolve(base64data.substr('data:audio/flac;base64,'.length));
      };
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    };
  });
}

getUserMediaPromise()
  .then(recordAudioPromise)
  .then(function(base64Audio) {
    console.log('Got base64Audio', base64Audio.length);
    console.log(base64Audio);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    throw error;
  });
```

Comment: I don't think chrome is able to export a FLAC file. When I do send directly the blob to my server, save it as a `file.flac` and open it with VLC, I get "Codec : Opus" ==> it should be saved as `ogg`. By the way, why don't you send the blob directy, then do the conversion to FLAC server-side? Also, why do you need FLAC and why do you need a dataURI version?

Comment: You are right, it isn't.  :(